# Android JSON offline validation

Tags: android, json, exception, validation

I would like to validate one string fetched as a response from a server. The response must be a valid JSON string. Sometimes, when the user is over a network that requires authentication or a PHP error happens, the response isn't a valid JSON.

Android parser JSONTokener don't validates strings before parsing them, so under that cases the application throws a JSONException and force closes.

I catched the exception, but application is still closing.

My question is: Is there any JSON validator for objects and strings to validate them first and avoid parsing them if they have an invalid format?

Another solution is checking if string[0] has "{" or "[" but this solution isn't elegant and will miss a lot of errors. So I would like to use a full JSON validator.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://jsontools.berlios.de/ - Are you sure this is the only Exception being thrown?

Comment: Yes, it was JSONException, android does not catch it well most of times. Reference -> http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONException.html

Line 7 on section Class Overview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using GSON?

If so the library raises a JsonSyntaxException when parsing a malformed JSON string

If you are using android.util.JsonReader a MalformedJsonException is thrown by the JsonReader

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me a lot. Finally I'm using json-simple to avoid the Android app to reach the JSONException. I imported the .jar to the project so now I can validate JSONs before parsing them.

There are a lot of validators/parsers for Java available, so if anyone has the same problem maybe as Casabian said GSON could help you. There are a big list of JSON validators/parsers available in www.json.org for different programming languages.

Thanks for your support.

Casabian, I would like yo vote you for your answer, but i cannot. I need more reputation I'll do when i have. Thanks ;)

Comment: Voted up and marked as valid answer as I promised :)